# creating a query using a data in a list format

Tags: python

For this list:

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'm']
```

I need to create a query as follows:

```
(("a"[Journal]) OR ("b" [Journal]) OR ("c" [Journal]) OR ("d" [Journal]) OR ("m" [Journal])) AND ("2007/01/01"[Date] : "2017/12/31"[Date])
```

I tried to use "join" to print output but I could not create this query.

any suggestion?

Comment: What are you querying? If it's some sort of database you probably don't want to use string formatting.

Comment: I am going to sue pubmed to search for some journals.

Comment: OK, then assuming their API sanitizes the queries (I can't imagine it wouldn't), you should be fine to use string formatting here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You indeed need the `join` and a list comprehension:

```
pieces = ['("{}" [Journal])'.format(j) for j in mylist]
journal_list = " OR ".join(pieces)
query = "({}) {}".format(journal_list, more_stuff)
```

`more_stuff` is the "date" part of your query (say, `'AND ("2007/01/01"[Date] : "2017/12/31"[Date])'`.

Another approach (less Pythonic) is to apply the format function to the list of journals:

```
pieces = map('("{}" [Journal])'.format, mylist)
journal_list = " OR ".join(pieces)
query = "({}) {}".format(journal_list, more_stuff)
```

The result, of course, is the same.

Comment: There is no list comprehension in there ;p

Comment: @RafaelC Now, there is.

Comment: You dont have to use a list comprehension. The generator from before was just fine

Comment: @RafaelC I know. But it may be easier for the beginner to see how a list is created before it is joined.

Comment: It would probably be cleaner (and less error prone) to use `.format()` in both cases- for the [Journal] part, and to glue those to the `( OR ` part.

Comment: `join` is faster if you use a list as opposed to a generator, because the first thing join does if you pass it a generator is convert to a list anyways

Comment: @user3483203 Not sure if it maters for a 5-member list, but yes, you are right.